# Pressing "enter" in contenteditable area to trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, submit, enter

I am trying to create a question/answer interaction, where users can type in a food and see if my friend is allergic. The logic functions, but now people are complaining that when they hit "enter" after typing it breaks lines in their answer instead of trigger the button. Phone users find this especially frustrating since it requires extra taps to get out of the keypad, then click the button on the page.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssprockett/Ct2TU/27/).

I've tried this which stops the line breaks but still doesn't submit the answers:

```
$("#test").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#test").submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot "submit" a div. You can submit a `form`, not a div :)

Comment: The reason I use a div is so the editable area behaves like the rest of the sentence (i.e. the ? follows the length of the input, there's no clumsy outline around the text area, etc). Is there a way to submit the text in my div without resorting to a form and ruining my formatting?

Comment: you could use an input field and use css to style it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the HTML content of the `DIV` in a hidden field before submitting:

```
function doSubmit(){
    var div = document.getElementById('#test');
    var hidden = document.getElementById('#hidden');
    hidden.value = div.innerHTML;

    // finish submitting the form, e.g. document.forms['myform'].submit();
}
```